# Cannot draw-user-backgrounds on greeter, Mate 20.04

Tags: login, lightdm, mate, desktop-background, dconf

Fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1.  Issue did not exist on earlier Mate 20.04 version.  I have been running multiple users on Ubuntu for 10+ years (mostly vanilla flavor) and have never had this issue on any other release/flavor that I can remember.

No matter what I try, the slick-greeter will not honor users' backgrounds.  The desired result is for the greeter to change its background to reflect each user's desktop wallpaper as they are highlighted in the greeter list.  I have tried numerous permission changes on home folders and wallpaper images, gone through dconf settings for each user and as the lightdm "user." and nothing works. Gsettings and dconf-editor show the flag as "true."  If I specify a specific image for the background, it will display that as the default greeter background, but individual user settings are ignored.  Before I reformatted and reinstalled the system AGAIN, I also tried installing and using GDM3 and other lightdm greeters - all to no avail.
Here is the log bit I think is most relevant:

> [+0.00s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:166: Resetting dconf setting for background to default
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:166: Resetting dconf setting for background-color to default
> (blah blah blah...)
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:166: Resetting dconf setting for enable-hidpi to default
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:166: Resetting dconf setting for only-on-monitor to default
> **[+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:175: Overriding dconf setting for draw-user-backgrounds**
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:184: Resetting dconf setting for draw-grid to default
> [+0.00s] DEBUG: settings.vala:184: Resetting dconf setting for show-hostname to default

the rest of the settings continue "Resetting dconf setting for..."

I should NOT be spending this much time on such a trivial thing, but it is driving me absolutely mad. My next step is to reformat and reinstall the earlier Mate image, but I would rather understand the problem and solution.

Comment: Please report this to https://bugs.launchpad.net and http://ubuntu-mate.community/ too with complete list of steps to reproduce. Did you tried to test this on fresh VM?